# Using Tesla A100 GPU with Kubeflow Pipelines on Vertex AI

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm using the following lines of code to specify the desired machine type and accelerator/GPU on a Kubeflow Pipeline (KFP) that I will be running on a serverless manner through Vertex AI/Pipelines.

```
op().
set_cpu_limit(8).
set_memory_limit(50G).
add_node_selector_constraint('cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator', 'nvidia-tesla-k80').
set_gpu_limit(1)
```

and it works for other GPUs as well i.e. Pascal, Tesla, Volta cards.

However, I can't do the same with the latest accelerator type which is the `Tesla A100` as it requires a special machine type, which is as least an `a2-highgpu-1g`.

How do I make sure that this particular component will run on top of `a2-highgpu-1g` when I run it on Vertex?

If i simply follow the method for older GPUs:

```
op().
set_cpu_limit(12). # max for A2-highgpu-1g
set_memory_limit(85G). # max for A2-highgpu-1g
add_node_selector_constraint('cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator', 'nvidia-tesla-a100').
set_gpu_limit(1)
```

It throws an error when run/deployed since the machine type that is being spawned is the general type i.e. N1-Highmem-*

Same thing happened when I did not specify the cpu and memory limits, in hope that it will automatically select the right machnie type based on the accelerator constraint.

```
    op().
    add_node_selector_constraint('cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator', 'nvidia-tesla-a100').
    set_gpu_limit(1)
```

Error:
`"NVIDIA_TESLA_A100" is not supported for machine type "n1-highmem-2",`

Comment: In which region you are running your GCP srvice? `Tesla A100` is quite limited about region which can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/regions#region_considerations) Could you share your whole code without private information? I guess it looks similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline#specify-machine-type)

Comment: The pipeline was executed on `/locations/us-central1/` and `A2 Machine Type` and `A100 GPUs` should be generally available to the region `us-central1` as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, GCP don't support A2 Machine type for normal KF Components. A potential workaround right now is to use [**GCP custom job component**](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job) that you can explicitly specify the machine type.